# Does the ORM call init when retrieving a saved instance?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'm doing a migration changing a nullable field to be not-nullable.  The new `__init__` routine ensures that fields can't be null by doing some custom callisthenics to come up with a suitable default.

The question is whether it is essential to migrate the existing data to apply the new rules for a default, or will those rules be applied automagically whenever a legacy object is retrieved?

[Reading the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L469) I suspect the ORM restores a pickle of the saved data, thus I would need to update all the old records.  But I need another set of eyes.

Does the ORM call init when retrieving a saved instance?

Comment: I dont have an answer for you but every time I need to do something similar, first I will update the model file, then I will manually update the DB through MySQL Workbench etc. Then I will run a fake migration. For some reason, I just dont trust Django when it comes to these kind of things. Just my 0.02.

Comment: Note that the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model) recommend not to override `__init__()`. If you change the field to not-nullable, you need to change the old data anyway so it doesn't violate the new constraint after you migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `__init__` get called on a model when django creates a model instance? The short answer is yes. If you use get or if you slice a queryset or iterate through it `__init__` will be called.

```
MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
MyModel.objects.all()[2]
for p in MyModel.objects.all():
   print p.pk
```

however overriding `__init__` isn't the recommended way to control model loading behaviour. That ought to be done with [from_db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.from_db)

> The from_db() method can be used to customize model instance creation
>   when loading from the database.
>
> The db argument contains the database alias for the database the model
>   is loaded from, field_names contains the names of all loaded fields,
>   and values contains the loaded values for each field in field_names.

Comment: Confirmed: I stuck a print inside the init and created and saved an instance.  Then using `get` to retrieve it does indeed print "I AM INIT" a second time.