# Django multi model form, save or update on one model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have 2 models in 1 form. in this form data can be changed.
For 1 model (Sloep_core) the content only have to update, this is working.
for the other model (Sloep_gegevens) the content normaly will update. 
Only if the value 'sloepnaam' changed in the form for model 'Sloep_gegevens', the record for the model 'Sloep_gegevens' must enter a new record and not update the old one. 
The save() must change from update to insert, but how??

I have tried to put soms code together (with some search actions). I come to the code below but now it is always a insert the code. Is someone have a idea to get it right?

model.py:

```
class Sloep_core(models.Model):
        FSN_nummer = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
        HT_nummer = models.IntegerField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
        SRNL_nummer = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        sloep_type = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
        werf =  models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        info = models.TextField(blank=True)
        objects = SloepManager()

        def __str__(self):
                return str(self.FSN_nummer)

class Sloep_gegevens(models.Model):
        sloep = models.ForeignKey(Sloep_core, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
        sloepnaam = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        thuishaven = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
        date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
        __original_sloepnaam = None

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super(Sloep_gegevens, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                self.__original_sloepnaam = self.sloepnaam

        def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
                if self.sloepnaam != self.__original_sloepnaam:
                        #  then do this
                        force_insert = True
                else:
                        #  do that
                        force_update = True

                super(Sloep_gegevens, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
                self.__original_sloepnaam = self.sloepnaam

        class Meta:
                ordering = ["date"]

        def __str__(self):
                return self.sloepnaam
```

form.py:

```
class SloepGegevensForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
                model = Sloep_gegevens
                exclude = ['pk', 'sloep']

class SloepCoreForm(forms.ModelForm):          
        class Meta:
                model = Sloep_core
                exclude = ['pk', 'SRNL_nummer']
```

views.py:

```
def sloep_edit(request, pk):
    sloep = Sloep_core.objects.get(pk=pk)
    sloep_sg = Sloep_gegevens.objects.filter(sloep=pk).order_by('-date')[0]
    if request.method == "POST":
        formSG = SloepGegevensForm(request.POST)
        formSC = SloepCoreForm(request.POST, instance=sloep)
        if all([formSG.is_valid(), formSC.is_valid()]):
            sloep = formSC.save()
            SG = formSG.save(commit=False)
            SG.sloep = sloep
            SG.save()
            return redirect('sloep_detail', pk=sloep.pk)
    else:
        formSG = SloepGegevensForm(instance=sloep_sg)
        formSC = SloepCoreForm(instance=sloep)
    return render(
        request,
        'sloepen/sloep_edit.html',
        {'formSG': formSG, 'formSC': formSC,})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the ORM call init when retrieving a saved instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37175724/does-the-orm-call-init-when-retrieving-a-saved-instance)

Comment: i don't see where it is e dupilcate of this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for my problem. In the view I didn't give a pk with the SloepGegevensForm in the POST request.model.
I changed: `formSG = SloepGegevensForm(request.POST)`into `formSG = SloepGegevensForm(request.POST, instance=sloep_sg)`
This makes the save() working.